# picturebox returns error while saving userdefined to byte array

Tags: c#

I seriusly need help as i cant figure this one out at all. It works fine when it uses the resources image to save into the byte arrat BUT when there is a user defined image it should use that one and save it to the array and the program chrashes and i just cant find the problem.

the code:

```
        //Check for image and if true save it to byte array
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {               
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                arr = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                AnimalMotel.Properties.Resources.nophotos.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                arr = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

The ELSE part here works perfect, the problem arises when there is a user defined image then it crashes and gives this:

```
  An unhandled exception of type 
  'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' 
  occurred in System.Drawing.dll

  Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

Prev code:

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.Bmp)|*.Bmp|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(myStream);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using the same size image and in Bmp format so it should not be because of that i belive.

Comment: Try save it as `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png`, perhaps your image is using some properties that is not supported by the `Bmp` format?

Comment: Anyways, where is the code that puts an image into `pictureBox1.Image`?

Comment: According to MSDN, this exception occurs when the image is saved in the wrong format. [See article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitmap class is a bit picky about streams. I worked much with bitmaps like five years ago and I have a thought that the error might be that you've disposed the original stream that you've opened from the OpenFileDialog. In some image formats I think that stream needs to be open to do operations like save.

Try and leave it open (comment out the `using(myStream)` statement) and see if it helps.

Comment: If you really need to do `Stream.Dipsose()` and remove the lock on the disk file I think you'll need to copy the image by saving the image to a `MemoryStream` and *after that* load it into a `Bitmap` and assign it to pictureBox. If your original file had been a `Png` file I don't think you would have had this problem.

Comment: Since this was the big issue i had with the form i am now cleaning up the code and for now i just have thrown the byte arrays into a list for storage and access as the user will be able to look thrue the list. I will do a couple of test later today to see if it was the bmp that gave me all these issues and if so...sayonara bmp!! ;) Thanks again for your time! Have a great day!!

Comment: Yes it comes back to me. I remember staring at "A generic error occurred in GDI+." back then for what now seems like hours...